# Slashes removed from variable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a variable that I am getting from an image's source attribute. When I set that variable as the background of an element using the style tag, all of the slashes are stripped out of it. Here is some of my code:

```
var logo    =   $('.logo-list li.selected-logo img').attr('src');
$('.stage').append('<div class="doc-header"><div class="product-logo"></div><div class="logo-small" style="background:url('+logo+');"></div></div>');
```

When I set an alert for the variable 'logo' it looks fine:
http://www.example.com/images/img.jpg

But when jQuery appends the code, the background attribute's URL looks like this: http: example.com images img.jpg

For some reason the slashes are getting removed/escaped, I just don't know why. Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Try using `encodeURIComponent(logo)`

Comment: seems like there is a double quote before url which should not be there

Comment: You have one too many double-quotes in there as well. `style="background:"url('+logo+');"` should not have a double-quote after `background:`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up in the double quote. I removed that in my code and edited my question. @BradM is close with encodeURIComponent(logo), but that actually encodes the url, like this http%3A%2F%2F... At least the slashes are there though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix it by using decodeURIComponent, thanks to @BradM's suggestion.

```
var logo    =   $('.logo-list li.selected-logo img').attr('src');
var logo    =   decodeURIComponent(logo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is an extra double quote here `"background:"url`. Remove the second double quote and should work fine

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4KSgj/3/)**

Comment: That was not the problem. I needed to use decodeURIComponent.

Comment: @ReLeaf: If you check my demo you'll see that removing the extra quotes worked for me.

Comment: I see that, but making that change didn't fix my problem. As you can see, if you add an extra double quote to your demo where I had it, it doesn't remove those slashes, it just writes malformed HTML. As I said before, I needed to use the decodeURIComponent to prevent the unwanted removal of the forward slashes. I should note that the code I provided above is a much smaller piece of a larger function that I did not include in my question. Perhaps something in that larger function was causing the issue with the URL. Regardless, thanks for your help.

Comment: @ReLeaf: Adding the extra double quotes you had allowed me to recreate the exacly same problem you were describing http://jsfiddle.net/4KSgj/5/. (use a any browser developer tool to examine html). In any case, I'm glad you solved this problem and if you're sure that `decodeURIComponent` is necessary to solve your problem I'll assume you're correct taking into account some context that I could be missing.