# How to avoid jquery to remove slash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I get url images via jquery getJSON but then jquery remove slashes:

```
//jquery remove slashes:
$("#imgjson").append('<img src"' + field.images[0] + '" /> ');
//here the slashes are not removed:
alert(field.images[0]);
```

and I get something like this:

```
<img src"http:="" cdn.google.biz="" 34="" test.jpg"="">
```

instead of this:

```
<img src"http://cdn.google.biz/34/test.jpg" />
```

How can I avoid that ?

Comment: can you show the structure of `field`?, there's also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389786/slashes-removed-from-variable

Comment: why always blame jQuery ..

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not with the slashes. You need to add `=` for `src` attribute:

```
$("#imgjson").append('<img src="' + field.images[0] + '" /> ');
//                            ^
```

Otherwise, the value of `field.images[0]` will not be considered as the `src` attribute value. It'll be considered as other attributes of `<img>` element.

**Demo**

```js
var field = {
  images: [
    "https://media4.giphy.com/media/1UYGwFDvZvnmo/200_s.gif"
  ]
};

$("#imgjson").append('<img src="' + field.images[0] + '" /> ');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgjson"></div>
```